# Scaladoc (and Javadoc) for Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Does scaladoc/javadoc for Apache Kafka exist somewhere on the web?

(yes, I can download the sources and generate it for personal use, but for quoting in emails/conversations a URL comes very handy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked myself the same question just some days ago, and it seems that the answer is still "no".

What worked for me was generating everything locally (as you mention) and then publish the html in an intranet server to address linking/conversational needs.

If you need something "public", I guess a [Github project page](https://github.com/apache/kafka) will be good enough, until Kafka 1.0 ready.

Answer (score 3):

For a more recent update to this question, javadocs are now available.

> [0.9.0](http://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/)
>
> [0.8.2](http://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/)

Comment: Useless. No docs at all for consumers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @morgan09dev, you can find documentation for the scala code in the following links which consists of the old producer and consumer apis and the broker part:

[0.9.0.1](http://apache.uberglobalmirror.com/kafka/0.9.0.1/scaladoc/index.html#package)

[0.8.2.2](http://apache.uberglobalmirror.com/kafka/0.8.2.2/scaladoc/index.html#package)